# Python show all installed packages

Tags: python, linux, yum, apt

Is there a way for python to show all apt/yum packages installed on a server? I have a program that can only grab one package that I specify but I'd like to know if there is a apt-show-versions/yum check-update like module in python since python-yum and python-apt only do single packages.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the code I have currently:

```
# For finding the package version and using the package name -i
def aptpkg(package_name):
    cache = apt.Cache()
    pkg = cache[package_name]
    host = subprocess.Popen('hostname', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stdout.read().strip()
    if pkg.is_installed:
        print host
        print 'Current ' + package_name + ' installed:', pkg.installed.version
        con.execute("insert into ansible_packagelist(date, host, package_name, installed_version) values (current_timestamp,%s,%s,%s)", (host, package_name, pkg.installed.version,))
    else:
        print host, package_name + ' is not installed on this system.\n'
    if pkg.is_upgradable:
        print 'Upgradeable version of ' + package_name + ' :', pkg.candidate.version
        con.execute("update ansible_packagelist set upgradeable_version = %s where package_name = %s", (pkg.candidate.version, package_name))
    db.commit()
```

Comment: can you paste your code that you have currently?

Comment: Have you tried `[p for p in apt_pkg.packages if p.is_installed]`? http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt_pkg.html#apt_pkg.packages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the pythonic way:

```
import apt
cache = apt.Cache()

for mypkg in cache:
    if cache[mypkg.name].is_installed:
        print mypkg.name
```

For yum, I need first to login to RH/Centos system.
But you can have a look to the yum library and you'll find something like 'rpmdb.searchNevra'

Comment: I think the `cache = apt.Cache()` on the second line is superfluous?

Answer (score 3):

Use `subprocess` to run a shell command.

```
from subprocess import call
```

for apt: `call(["dpkg", "-l"])`

for yum : `call(["yum list installed"])`

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am looking for a module not a bash work around.

Comment: @Nvasion Maybe you'd like to use `import socket; host = socket.gethostname();` to avoid the hostname child process.

Answer (score 3):

maxadamo's answer is correct, but the `Cache` is initialized twice and I don't know why.

You can instantiate only one cache instead, loop over it and access the `pkg` directly in the for-loop. You don't need the extra lookup, as you already have access to the `pkg`'s attributes.

So here's a more Pythonic way:

```
import apt
cache = apt.Cache()

for pkg in cache:
    if pkg.is_installed:
        print pkg.name
```

Comment: you could have fixed my reply :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

with open("/var/lib/dpkg/status", "r") as f:
    status = f.read()
    packages_installed = re.findall("Package: (.*)\nStatus: install ok installed", status)
```

You have to read about dpkg packages status. Exec: "man dpkg" and go to "INFORMATION ABOUT PACKAGES" section.

I think that use modules for some problems is unnecessary. It creates dependencies (I do not like that). And the "simple" script is faster than the script that uses apt module.
Comparation:

a.py:

```
    import re

with open("/var/lib/dpkg/status", "r") as f:
        status = f.read()
        packages_installed = re.findall("Package: (.*)\nStatus: install ok installed", status)
```

b.py:

```
 import apt
cache = apt.Cache()

for pkg in cache:
    pass
#        if pkg.is_installed:
#            print pkg.name
```

Times:

```
/tmp » time python a.py
    python a.py  0,04s user 0,01s system 58% cpu 0,075 total
/tmp » time python b.py
    python b.py  3,07s user 0,09s system 75% cpu 4,205 total
```

If the unique objective is get a list of installed packages, use apt module is not necessary. Other way is using subprocess and ejecute "dpkg -l", but I am not friend of exec.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to use answer with "import re"

be notified: 
some packages has another header

```
Package: perl-base
Essential: yes
Status: install ok installed
```

so this code will not works

if you still want to use it, needed to make changes like this:

```
re.findall("Package: (.*)\n(Essential: yes\n){,1}Status: install ok installed", status)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pip list` or `pip list > requirements.txt` and process the file manualy to generate a requirements.